# Button disabled effect not working after 1st click

Tags: jquery, css, button, disabled-control

I'm disabling a button with jQuery. It does work, but there is a strange behavior in Chrome. If I click on the button, it remains with the not-disabled color:

[image]

Only if I click again, or if I move the mouse (at least 1 px), the button is displayed as disabled:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<button id="reset" type="button">Reset</button>

$('#reset').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled',true);
});
```

For some reason, it does work fine on the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hjqk00j4/

In my localhost version, I tried stripping parts of the page, js chunks, css parts, etc, but it still won't display the disabled version of the button unless I click again on it. Any ideas?

Comment: Unless your version of jQuery is < 1.6, use `prop('disabled',true);` [**See this SO question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Does it fail in Chrome even if you use a super simple version of this with a <div> instead of a <button> tag? Seems like it could be a glitch in Chrome, perhaps related to the amount of fancy CSS techniques you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#reset').click(function(){
   $(this).attr('disabled',true);
   $(this).attr('disabled',false);
});
```